# accessing a file path that is in different package

Tags: java, path

I have a properties file that is present in project name/properties/dev folder. I am writing my code in project name/src folder. I want to update the properties file from java code. I am unable to get the path of  the properties file in   project name/ src folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class to get *.properties files. For example if you run your class directly from `project name/src`:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("../properties/dev/propfile.properties"); // you can use absolute path here if you want
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("../properties/dev/propfile.properties");
props.setProperty("Key", "Value");
props.store(out, "Comment"); // store changes
out.close();
```